# How to eliminate an annoying blue line in a border area of a hyperlink / h2 class with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm unable to resolve an issue with my CSS. For some annoying reason, a **dark blue vertical dash** appears to the left of the product image -- but it's part of either the amazon-buying class or asin-title class.  It looks like this:

[image: annoying blue line]

This is the only CSS I can find that would have anything to do with things:

```
.amazon-product-table {
    border-collapse : collapse;
    border : 0 none !important ;
    width : 100%;
}
.amazon-product-table td {
    border : 0 none !important ;
    padding : 0 !important ;
}
div.amazon-image-wrapper {
    text-align : center;
    width : 170px;
    float : left;
    padding : 0 10px 0 10px;
}

div.amazon-buying {
    text-align : left;
}
h2.amazon-asin-title {
    margin : 0 0 5px 0;
    line-height : 1.25;
    font-size : 10pt;
}
span.asin-title {
    text-align : left;
}
```

Here is what Firebug is showing:

[image: Firebug]

I'm not good with CSS to begin with, but I'm completely clueless on how to eliminate this dark blue line -- whatever it is.  It appears to be part of the title, or the amazon-buying class; when I hover over those classes in Firebug, that's the 665x16px area that highlights.

Here's a [live example](http://www.thekidneybean.com/2014/01/25/the-10-must-have-pairs-of-shoes/) of the issue I'm dealing with.  I've exhausted everything I could think of. Any guidance in helping me eliminate this **annoying blue line** would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are giving it a left border... `border-left: 4px solid #34495e;` on `.container .post-entry h2`... doesn't really seem like you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the element with the border:

[image]

As to getting rid of it, you could probably do something like this:

```
.amazon-product-table .amazon-asin-title {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Blender!  That code worked perfectly!  No more annoying left border!  I really wish I had your CSS knowledge -- it would save me hours on end.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 2):

Here is where it's being applied:

```
.container .post-entry h2 {
    border-left: 4px solid #34495e;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    font: bold 14px Arial;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

If you can't remove the `border-left` property, you would overwrite it with the following:

```
.container .post-entry h2 {
    border-left: none;
}
```

If that doesn't work, here is a more specific selector that will:

```
.container .post-entry h2.amazon-asin-title {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Josh.  The first CSS snippet worked perfectly!  The second didn't, but that doesn't matter now.  But at last I understand now, via your explanation as to where the CSS is coming from -- it's being inherited from the main stylesheet.  Thank you for taking the time to respond and provide an explanation!